# Is it possible to add script breaking line in R, like the cell break in Matlab

Tags: r, matlab

I have been using R for a while. Sometimes it is quite annoying that when the script gets long, then you have to add a break line to separate the code. Is it possible to add script breaking line automatically, like the cell break in Matlab.

something like this:

code 1

---

code 2

Thanks:)

Best, Qin

Comment: I'm really not quite sure what are you talking about. Scripts can definitely be multiline, just hit Enter when you need it.

Comment: @January I think Qin Wang is referring to Matlab's cell mode, not multiline commands or line breaks in general. http://www.mathworks.com/company/newsletters/news_notes/dec04/cellmode.html

Comment: @Tobold yes, but then, Cell Mode is not about automatic line breaks.

Comment: @January Yes, I agree, that of course doesn't happen automatically. The question is not very clear. What's a "script breaking line"/"break line" supposed to be and in what sense should that happen "automatically"?

Comment: depending on what you mean (which isn't clear) you could add a line of `####################################` ...

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by @BenBolker , if you are under emacs ess, you can try <kbd>Ctrl-u</kbd> <kbd>40</kbd><kbd>#</kbd> to produce 40 `#` comment sign to separate code chunk.

Comment: In RStudio, you can go Code > Insert Section, or Ctrl + Shift + R